# Как в Android studio включить отображение типов?

Tags: android, android-studio, настройки

Как в Android studio включить отображение типов?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если все же требуется не отображать данные в Editor, а одноразово посмотреть тип можно нажать CTRL+Q и сбоку в окне отобразится тип переменой

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы включить подсказки типов в `Android Studio` нужно перейти: File -> Settings -> Editor -> Inlay Hints -> Kotlin/Java -> Show parameter hints

Answer (score 3):

Можно нажать быстро 2 раза Shift и ввести Hints. И оттуда перейти в настройки.

Подобный способ очень хорошо подходит для поиска любых настроек.

**UPD:** А как подсказал @Leshka Cntrl + Shift + A (command + Shift + A для mac) сразу откроет вкладку "Actions"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+A сразу спозиционируется на действиях

Comment: Спасибо за уточнение. Дополнил ответ